# Im trying to display data from a local json file using dynatable, but i'm getting undefined in values in the table?

Tags: jquery, html, dynatable

I installed dynatable and I wanted to create table from data written in JSON. My table with script:

```html
      <table id="university_Table">
        <thead>
          <th>University</th>
          <th>Link</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var json_url = 'universities.json';
  $.getJSON(json_url, function(data) {
    $('#university_Table').dynatable({
      table: {
        defaultColumnIdStyle: 'lowercase'
      },
      dataset: {
        records: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My Json file looks like this:

```
[{
  web_page: "http://www.meu.edu.jo/",
  country: "Jordan",
  domain: "meu.edu.jo",
  name: "Middle East University"
},{
  web_page: "http://www.odtu.edu.tr/",
  country: "Turkey",
  domain: "odtu.edu.tr",
  name: "Middle East Technical University"
 },
 //...
```

This is the result I'm getting on the table:

[image: And this is the result I'm getting on the table]

I have followed the documentation on their website, as well as looked at some other posts on stack overflow but the advice they've given hasn't been able to help me with this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Aside from the main issue, but `records: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` is redundant. Just `records: data` is enough

Comment: put console.log(data) check what is returning from ajax

Comment: can you please make a fiddle